# Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I am creating a game that has players swiping the planes into the correct lanes. However, I recently added a airplane to my game screen. However, Xcode says that I am using and undeclared identifier. I am new to this so please help.

Here is my header file controlling the game.
GamePlayViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GamePlayViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Here is my GamePlayViewController.m This is where the error appears.

```
    #import "GamePlayViewController.h"

#import "Airplane.h"

@interface GamePlayViewController ()

@end

@implementation GamePlayViewController

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //Add a vehicle
    Airplane* v = [[Airplane alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(221, 228, 0, 0)
                   [self.view addSubview:v];
}

@end
```

The error is at the Airplane* v [[Airplane alloc]. It says Use of undeclared identifier "Airplane" and also "v"

I have searched all over Google and Stackoverflow for the answer, but none of the scenarios matched my situation.

By the way, thanks in advance to whoever answers.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: change `Airplane* v = [[Airplane alloc]` to `CAAAirplane* v = [[CAAAirplane alloc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you declare image from this line?

```
image = [loadedImage retain];
```

my guess is you don't.

---

Add this:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
```

...to your .h, and this to your .m:

```
@synthesize image;
```

Comment: Should probably post an all new question. Your new edit changes it dramatically, and would be confusing to future readers